# How can I apply black color for bold text in highlighted region?

Tags: faces, region, highlighting

I am using [dracula-theme](https://github.com/dracula/emacs/blob/master/dracula-theme.el). Only change I did is adding following line under `(faces '`:

```
(faces '(;; default / basic faces
    (region :background ,dracula-yellow :foreground ,dracula-black :extend t)
```

---

Normal  color:

[image]

When I highlight a region, bolded text's color becomes slightly gray instead of black, but unbolded text is black.

[image]

Would it be possible to for to make color of bolded text to black when its highlighted?

Comment: Do you see the problem with `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: I just have `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes");
(load "dracula-theme.el")` in my init file. But starting it using `emacs -nw` or `emacs -q -nw -l init.el`  differs from each other

Comment: If don't see the problem with `emacs -Q` then something in your init file is the culprit. That's the bottom line.

Comment: In `emacs -Q` I see the same problem. You should see something like this https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/ffb60939001af969c71ae9f07413dcdf?permalink_comment_id=4118589#gistcomment-4118589  , where bold string is gray on the highlighted region.

Comment: So it's not from your init file (e.g. loading some theme). In that case, consider filing a bug report / enhancement request, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Drew Yes sir, I am pretty sure I end up a question related to this but I was not able to find it in stackoverflow, it was a well known issue. When the region is highlighted its hard to read the colorful text on it so I just made the font black on top of the highlighted yellow region. But bold text is auto converted into gray instead of black.

Comment: @Drew it was a basic solution but changed font color in region from black to `darkblue` made gray font gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a small hack but helped, I change the font color from black to `darkblue` for the `region`. Colors slightly improved and become sharper.

```
(custom-set-variables
    (region ((t (:extend t :background "#f1fa8c" :foreground "darkblue")))))
```

Example output:

[image]